LinkedIn API Token Revocation without Manual Intervention
I’m encountering an issue where my LinkedIn API token is being revoked unexpectedly without any manual action on our end. This is happening daily and is causing significant disruption to our application’
Details of the Issue:
Problem: LinkedIn API token is automatically revoked, causing the application to lose authentication.
Frequency: The revocation occurs on a daily basis.
Platform: Mendix application integrated with LinkedIn API.
Impact: The token revocation forces us to re-authenticate and refresh the token frequently, which interrupts the flow and impacts productivity.
Ensured that token refresh logic is implemented correctly.
Checked for any issues with the integration.
Verified that no manual changes are being made to the token on our end.
Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Questions:
Is there a known issue with LinkedIn API tokens being revoked automatically?
Are there any known configurations or adjustments we should make to prevent token revocation?
What might be causing the token to expire or get revoked without manual intervention?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
